# How to Change Background of UIWebView Scrolling?

Tags: iphone

in the iPhone SDK Interface Builder, any UIWebView has a default gray background that is shown when the view has been scrolled too far. Is it possible to change this background color so it doesn't look so obvious? The gray conflicts with my App :( Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

```
webView.backgroundColor = yourcolor;
```

You can even do it in IB.

Comment: @MartinReichl I rechecked with iOS 4.3 and worked fine for me. Can you provide the instructions to reproduce the error? Are you talking about the web page's background color?

Answer (score 4):

```
   id scrollView = [[[self yourWebView] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
   if([scrollView respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:)] )
   {
      [scrollView performSelector:@selector(setBackgroundColor:) 
                       withObject:[UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor]];
   }
```

Comment: It is definitely not safe to grab the subview at index 0 for a UIWebView, as that is a private implementation detail and subject to change (the view at index 0 could be a different type of view in a future version of the SDK). It would be better to iterate through and find views that respond to setBackgroundColor: instead.